# How to call an aysnc function properly in javascript?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

can you call an async function with .then().catch() construct ?

```
const bar = require('./foofile');
let result = '';
bar.fooFunc()
.then(function(data){
  data.forEach(function(value){
     //add a new line
     result += `${value}`;
  })
})
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

file : foofile.js

```
async function fooFunc(){
  //this returns an array
}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you've encountered when you tried this?

Comment: Yes, you can. `async` functions return promises.

Comment: But note that `result` will remain blank until the promise has been fulfilled; [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - so how do i make sure , i get the result , either success or failure.

Comment: @arve - I don't quite understand what you mean by that. If the promise is fulfilled, your fulfillment (`then`) handler will get called. If it's rejected (or an error occurs in your fulfillment handler), your rejection (`catch`) handler will get called. If you just want to know when it settles but you don't care how (fulfillment vs. rejection), use `finally`.

Comment: @arve: *"can you call an async function with .then().catch() construct ?"* - Yes.  And the code you're showing does exactly that.  Is something not working in some way?

Comment: @David- I am calling a pdfjs library , in my fooFunc(). and inside my  then clause, i am saving it to a text file. I am testing this and , it keeps saving an empty text file, and i dont' catch any errors either. so i wanted to make sure , i am calling it right

Comment: @arve: The code shown isn't doing any of what you describe.  *Most likely* you're just trying to use the result of the asynchronous operation before that operation has actually completed.  But that's mostly a guess since the code shown never actually does anything with the result.  So, yes, according to the code shown you are "calling it right".